# How can I apply a gradual blur to a background image (so that a text overlay is easily readable)?

Tags: css, html, image

I have a large photo, such as http://www.bestwallpapersfan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/1755137.jpg.  I want to overlay text near its bottom.

To ensure that the text is readable, I want to use the Floor Blur approach described here: https://medium.com/@erikdkennedy/7-rules-for-creating-gorgeous-ui-part-2-430de537ba96#dc39-765a9789c924

I've learned how to do a simple Floor Fade to Black or a simple blur (both described here: https://css-tricks.com/design-considerations-text-images/).

But how do I combine the effects such that it's a gradual / gradient / progressive blur?

Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote on this question?  (I wish it were required for downvoters to offer constructive criticism; otherwise how will this community improve?)

Comment: I've wished for the same explanation requirement, too. I suspect the downvoter wanted to see some code with your question. Although SO is a coding site, some SO viewers seem overly obsessed with code. To me your question seems clear enough without code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty close to what I was looking for and now just needs to be cleaned up to fix the funkiness with the h1, etc.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.gradient {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9));
  opacity: 0.99;
  z-index: 2;
}

.module {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/skyscrapers.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.module>header {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
}

.module>header::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
  filter: blur(12px);
  transform: scale(2) translateY(20px);
}

.module>header>h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gradient">
  </div>
  <div class="module">
    <header>
      <h1>
        Skyscraper
      </h1>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Skyscraper
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You could use html5 canvas to draw that progressive gradient**

White text annotation without a progressive gradient:

[image]

Annotation with a progressive gradient:

[image]

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/annotateMe.jpg";
function start(){
  cw=canvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  var g=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,ch-100,0,ch);
  g.addColorStop(0.00,'rgba(0,0,0,.1)');
  g.addColorStop(1.00,'rgba(0,0,0,.75)');
  ctx.fillStyle=g;
  ctx.fillRect(0,ch-100,cw,100);

  ctx.fillStyle='white';
  ctx.font='24px verdana';
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='bottom';
  ctx.fillText('Natural Beauty',cw/2,ch-5);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Isn't this just adding a gradient of darkness and not blurriness?

Comment: Yep--its a gradient only. You can do a blur also, but if the intent is to contrast the text then darkening without destroying content visibility (blurring) is useful -- and much faster.  If you want to blur, here is a nice lib that does that: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html. Note that blurs are performance killers, so workarounds not using blurs are useful. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You've complicated a bit too much, try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8fjqffq/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Skyscraper</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/skyscrapers.jpg);
}
.container,
#header {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;;  
}
#header {
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}
h1 {
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#ffffff;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:101;
  text-align:center;
  /* Gradient to h1 */
  background: rgba(255,93,177,0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,93,177,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,93,177,0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,93,177,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,93,177,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,93,177,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,93,177,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff5db1', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0 );
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I don't see a blur in there at all.